# Why is Nrisimha not a fierce form of God?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism

[image]

Srimad-Bhagavatam 1/2/26 says:

> Those who want salvation **reject the fierce forms** like Bhutapati without having any hatred against them and worship the gentle forms of Narayana.

But Sri Nrisimha is worshipped by the Vaishnavas in many forms.

Why is this 'Nrisimha' form of Sri Vishnu not treated as 'fierce'? Kindly state the scriptural reason.

Comment: Narasimha was fierce only during the killing of Hiranyakasipu. After Prahlada's prayer, he calmed down. There are representations of Narasimha with a calm demeanor at many places.

Comment: @LazyLubber But the form still looks fierce as compared to the other very gentle and sweet forms of Sri Vishnu

Comment: In many cases he is also shown to be gentle with either Lakshmi or Prahlada on lap.

Comment: Ok. Regional variation then. Quite common.

Comment: "After Prahlada's prayer, he calmed down. ". No he went insane and Shiva had to send an avatara to calm him down.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I told the Bhagavata version. You are giving a sectarian version.

Comment: @LazyLubber Actually, it is mentioned in Shiva Purana that Shiva took the form of Sharabha to calm Narasimha.

Comment: @Surya May be. But that is clearly sectarian. The Bhagavata, from which the question is asked, merely states that after Prahlada's prayers, Narasimha calmed down.

Comment: @LazyLubber I think it's because of Kalpa-bheda.

Comment: @Surya I think it is simply plain and blatant sectarianism.

Comment: I think Vaishnavas only worship YogaNarasimha, LakshmiNarasimha and Sudarshana-Narasimha.

Comment: @user1952500 no in Bengal:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lazy Luber pointed out, Lord's anger was temporary .

His form is described as wonderful as well in Bhagavatam:

SB 7.8.17:

> adṛśyatāty**adbhuta-rūpam** udvahan -- wonderful form

SB 7.9.1:

> dṛṣṭvā taṁ mahad **adbhutam**
>   adṛṣṭāśruta-pūrvatvāt

As soon as Prahlada approached Lord, he became very peaceful..

SB 7.9.5:

> When Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva saw the small boy Prahlāda Mahārāja prostrated at the soles of His lotus feet, He became most ecstatic in affection toward His devotee. Raising Prahlāda, the Lord placed His lotus hand upon the boy’s head **because His hand is always ready to create fearlessness in all of His devotees.**

Thus, Prahlada says that this form is to be remembered to become free from fear:

> ad yaccha manyum asuraś ca hatas tvayādya
>   modeta sādhur api vṛścika-sarpa-hatyā
>   lokāś ca nirvṛtim itāḥ pratiyanti sarve
>   **rūpaṁ nṛsiṁha vibhayāya janāḥ smaranti**

SB 7.9.14:

> My Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva, please, therefore, cease Your anger now that my father, the great demon Hiraṇyakaśipu, has been killed. Since even saintly persons take pleasure in the killing of a scorpion or a snake, all the worlds have achieved great satisfaction because of the death of this demon. Now they are confident of their happiness, and **they will always remember Your auspicious incarnation in order to be free from fear.**

SB 7.9.15:

> My Lord, who are never conquered by anyone, I am certainly not afraid of Your ferocious mouth and tongue, Your eyes bright like the sun or Your frowning eyebrows. I do not fear Your sharp, pinching teeth, Your garland of intestines, Your mane soaked with blood, or Your high, wedgelike ears. Nor do I fear Your tumultuous roaring, which makes elephants flee to distant places, or Your nails, which are meant to kill Your enemies.

Answer (score 4):

No form of Vishnu can display uncontrolled anger. Why is this so? Because one of the names of Vishnu is jitakrodah (name #462 in the Vishnu sahasranama of Mahabharata).

jitakrodah means - one who has conquered anger.

Shankara's (?) commentary on the Vishnu sahasranama is available at the link below -

https://archive.org/details/Vishnu.Sahasranama.with.the.Bhasya.of.Sankaracharya

Shankara (?) gives an interesting comment for this name. He says that Vishnu destroys the foes of the devas (gods), **not out of anger, but in order to protect righteousness.**

Hence, Narasimha, being a form of Vishnu, has conquered his anger, even though he appears angry and Narasimha kills Hiranyakasipu only to protect dharma and not for petty reasons. As Narasimha has conquered his anger, he is by nature not fierce.

Comment: Okay, but that must be true for any form of God! One Who has not conquered anger is no God!

Comment: @Pratimaputra Isn't your question specific to Narasimha.

Comment: yes, but with reference to the bhagavata sloka. I am upvoting your answe and wait for few more days.Thanks so much.:)

Comment: And ' Krodhakrit' is also a name of Vishnu btw:)

Comment: @Pratimaputra Ok, may be you can modify your question if you want to extend it to all gods.

Comment: @Pratimaputa The actual name is krodha krt kartaa - Shankara (?) comments - the creator of anger in wicked men or the slayer of angry asuras.

Comment: I mean, bhagavatam is advising to discard the fierce forms.So why a fierce form of Vishnu is worshipped so much even though He has many sweeter forms? That He has conquered anger iss okay and that trye for God in general.In that case no form shoukd be asked to be discarded,Hope I could make it clear?

Comment: okay, but krodha and krit can not remain separated like this according to sanskrit grammer.Its a single word and a single name.

Comment: @Pratimaputra We have to understand who exactly is Bhutapati here. It may not refer to Shiva.

Comment: I am not referring to Shiva. And its in vahu-vachana, meaning many such forms.

Comment: @Pratimaputra ok. The full name is not krodhakrt but krodhakrtkartaa. Thats all I wanted to point out.

Comment: @Pratimaputra It could be of some lesser god who has not controlled his anger.

Comment: krodhakrit-karta can have a meaning like the 'Doer (Karta) who is angry (Krodhakrit) also. Just like the Gaudiyas explain 'sannyasa-krit' as The One Who actually has taken sannyasa. The meaning given by Sankar is different of course, but Gaudiyas are not incorrect at least grammatically.

Comment: @Pratimaputra I am not expert in Sanskrit grammar, so I cannot comment. I would go with Shankara's reading as it does good samanvaya with other names.