# Is there any easy technique written in Bhagavad GITA to control lust?

Tags: indriyas, kama

Is there any easy technique written in Bhagavad GITA or any religious books to control lust/self-pleasure?

Comment: easiest is diet. One needs to cut down on rajasic/tamasic foods in life. Stick to sattvic foods.

Comment: mainly avoid meat, onion, garlic, mushroom, drumstick. go on fruit diet for a day or two. you'll immediately see how your mind doesn't hanker as much

Comment: @Ram,,,, i daily  eat chicken burger, chicken briyani ,chicken -Momos, tandoori chicken.....hot dogs etc..

Comment: okss @gansub..i  will try  to avoid  ...

Comment: Simple. Not only lust. Realize the consequences you will face of all negative traits, and then realize Paramatma is everything and hence I will go towards him. The more you go towards Paramatma, all lusts leaves you automatically. Path of light destroys darkness in you. Foods are nothing because one of 63 Nayanmars used to give Lord Shiva Pig's flesh and he eats that because he was hunter. But Shiva gave his darshan to him. Devotion to Paramatma destroys everything darkness!

Comment: @AkshayS - food is nothing ? There is a HUGE difference between a Nayanmar and a neophyte devotee. That nayanmar was born in a hunter family and so for generations they used to eat wild boar meat. Each person is different. One's background and past life karma plays a huge part in it.

Comment: first you need to move out of the environment of lust basically the person you are lusting on... then this all yoga,niyama, yama, Dhyana and darshana applies, best thing do fast for 1 day without water on Ekadashi for love of god (Vishnu) and give the result to Krishna.. if you are not hindu.. then pray whatever diety and do fasting to arrest lust do it for 1 starting then increase no. of days of fasting based on your lusting intensity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way is  control of diet or aahahara as it is known in Sanskrit. There are two categories from Ayurveda - pathya and apathya. You need to stick to pathya foods. Pathya means restricted. By restriction I mean sattvic foods. One needs to completely avoid rajasic and tamasic foods. These are available by the dozen these days. From a modern contemporary Kali Yuga perspective these are the ubiquitous spicy masala foods and most definitely junk food. You need to figure out a diet which is nutritious and wholesome for you. By sattvic I mean do not starve yourself. A good Ayurvedic Vaidya would be helpful to guide you in this regard.

The BG offers a broad guideline on what the sattvic foods are - [Sattvic foods](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/8)
Please remember that there is a deity in the stomach - [Vaishvanara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishvanara) and this is mentioned in BG - [Digesting different kinds of food](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/15/14). During youth and middle age the stomach is able to bear the junk foods we eat. As time passes onto old age the karmic reactions will start to appear.

So the key question is what are sattvic foods in today's environment? A modern self realized Jnani has described what sattvic foods are [Ramana Maharishi diet recommendations](http://spiritualblossoms.blogspot.com/2010/08/sri-ramana-maharshi-diet.html)-

> Mrs. Piggott returned from Madras for a further visit. She asked questions relating to diet regulation.
>
> D.: What diet is prescribed for a sadhak (one who is engaged in spiritual practices)?
>
> M.: Satvic food in limited quantities.
>
> D.: What is satvic food?
>
> M.: Bread, fruits, vegetables, milk, etc.
>
> D.: Some people take fish in North India. May it be done?
>
> No answer was made by the Maharshi.

Care must also be given to how foods are prepared and the environment in which they are prepared. As I mention below a return to ancient traditional practices is what Sri Krishna is asking in BG and so usage of clay pots, cast iron skillet, kalchattis(cooking pot made with soapstone) and wooden ladle is strongly encouraged. If one goes to an Indian village today this is how traditional sattvic food is cooked and offered and then only consumed and following these practices will help the aspirant enormously.

A predominantly sattvic diet(with some rajasic spices) will have a definite impact on the dream state(which is where the lust/carnal pleasures get activated) i.e. during night. You need to also stop spending time in front of the computer and mobile phone beyond 7 pm i.e. eat early before 8 pm and avoid any internet and mobile after you eat. In ancient India there was no electricity as there is in modern homes. People used to light lamps and the house fire. So food was consumed after the evening sandhya and generally people used to sleep after their evening food or practise their sadhana.

[Following the path of the ancients](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/15) Modern Indian cities due to their highly populated areas are highly tamasic(noisy, dusty and congested) and so it would be beneficial to recreate the atmosphere of the ancients in our daily lives whenever time permits. Reconnecting with our roots in whatever possible (spending time in a village from time to time) or an ashrama that promotes an traditional lifestyle.

Comment: @sv , because question says "or any religious books"

Comment: @sv. I was told to remove certain portion in my answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34010/why-is-nrisimha-not-a-fierce-form-of-god by pratimaputra.. Check my edit history..What are the exact rules I should follow while writing answer?

Comment: @Pratimaputra- No more edits to this answer OK ? I have made what I consider final edits.

Comment: @gansub yes its your answer and ur decision is always final.

Answer (score 4):

I am quoting some relevant slokas from the Gita :

> 3.37 The Blessed Lord said **This lust, this anger, born of the quality of rajas, is a great devourer, a great sinner. Know this to be the enemy here.**
>
> 3.40 The organs, mind, and the intellect are said to be its abode. This one diversely deludes the embodied being by veiling Knowledge with the help of these.
>
> 3.41 Therefore, O scion of the Bharata dynasty, after first controlling the organs, renounce this one, which is sinful and a destroyer of learning and wisdom.
>
> 3.42 They say that the organs are superior (to the gross body); the mind is superior to the organs; but the intellect is superior to the mind. However, the one who is superior to the intellect is He [the Self].
>
> •3.43 **Understanding the Self thus [Understanding ৷৷ .thus:that lust can be conered through the knowledge of the Self.] as superior to the intellect, and completely establishing (the Self) is spiritual absorption with the (help of) the mind, O mighty-armed one, vanish the enemy in the form of lust, which is difficult to subdue.**
>
> 'AhAra-suddhau sattvasuddhih' is a very renowned saying. Pure sattvik food is a must in the beginning for all the spiritual aspirants.

Sri Ramakrishna is His Kathamrita recommends chanting of the NAma of God and changing the direction of the lust towards God as two ways to dominate lust.He also asks not be bothered much about the presence of lust in mind and focus on God. When one moves towards east, he automatically distances himself from west---said He. (Reference : Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita and Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Lilaprasanga)

Sri Bhagavan also says the same in His Gita:

> 18.66 Abandoning all forms of rites and duties, take refuge in Me alone. **I shall free you from all sins. (Therefore) do not grieve.**